# background image not displaying CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a gradient background image but for some unfortunate reason, it doesn't display. this is my CSS and my HTML:

```css
html {
  background: url("static/pexels-gradienta-7130555.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background_image">
    foobar
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you get a url error in your console?

Comment: @maksymiuk yes, 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2022 21:31:58] "GET /static/css/static/pexels-gradienta-7130555.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: So your url is bad, have you tried just going to `<domain>/static/css/static/pexels-gradienta-7130555.jpg` and seeing if it works?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is actually in that directory?

Comment: @maksymiuk doesn't seem to work either :(

Comment: @BlueGleam So you have to figure out where your image is first then your css will work

Comment: @maksymiuk Yes, it's there if I browse to my project folder both through the cmd and through file explorer.

Comment: do you have it set as copy to output directory?

Comment: Try providing a url photo image , it will work. You might have to upload image in the output folder when your deploy . The only reason it does not work is it does not map correctly to the path of your image. Locally it might work. But on server try to access the image path without worrying about the html page.

Comment: @SmithaKalluz that helped, thank you.

Comment: @BlueGleam please give me a upvote if it helped you:)

Comment: @SmithaKalluz don't have enough rep :(